# When to use computed/observables in mobx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I feel like I'm getting most of mobx, but I want to clarify something. I've got a store with some observables, the core of which is an array of objects (typescript):

```
class ClientStore {
    constructor() {
        this.loadClients();
    }

    @observable private _clients: IClient[] = [];
    @computed get clients() {
        return this._clients;
    }
    @observable isFetching: boolean = false;
    @observable sortField: 'title' | 'modified' = 'modified';
    @observable sortDescending: boolean = true;

    getClientByUrlName(urlName: string): IClient {
        return this._clients.find(c => c.urlName === urlName);
    }
etc...
```

My question is that last function - getClientByUrlName. Since that's finding from an observable, any @observer react component that's using that function re-renders correctly. Is this idiomatic mobx for something like that? It feels like that should be a computed value. Should I make is a computed value in the component that wants to use it?

```
//import singletone ClientStore
class ClientDetailsView extends React.Component<{params:{urlName:string}}, void> {

    @computed get client() {
        return ClientSotre.clients.find(c => c.urlName === this.props.params.urlName);
    }

...rest of react component
```

I'm looking for best practices and gotchas here. Any help is appreciated.

*edit fixed code sample error

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In principle `@computed` is simple a directive that tells MobX: "this value *could* be cached until any of the observables that is used changes". So in fact they can always be left out, it will just mean that your app will recompute more, but it doesn't alter the results.

So if you are missing `@computed` on the function that is in principle not a problem in most cases. If it is, you can use `createTransformer` which takes a one-argument function and builds a (self cleaning) memoization cache of computed values. But it is a little bit more involved, so actually your solution to introduce a computed property in your `ClientDetailsView` is nicer. I would indeed recommend doing that as long as you have a nice place to put that computed property (the component that needs it in this case)

Comment: Ah hah! That seemed like a piece I was missing. Every time I go over the docs I see a part as if it was brand new. Funny that sticking the computed property in the component itself came to me as I was writing the question.


[off topic] I'm really like MobX in general by the way (I'm converting from redux). The more I learn how it works the more I like it. Thanks for all the hard work!

Comment: I actually did restructure the docs the last days a bit, so that impression is right :)

Comment: I am a little confused why it would be better to put the `@computed` in the ClientDetailsView instead of in the store. Would putting it in the store have the same effect?

Comment: Getters can't have parameters, @computed has to be a getter, and the store itsn't aware of which urlName I'm looking for. On a higher level it makes sense that the store can't compute and memoize a value that it doesn't have enough information to get. The real solution is the createTransformer mentioned in the answer, as that makes the store memoize the value each time a new parameter is passed in, but in cases where it's overkill my solution feels simpler.  I actually like it for mine, as many components may access this value, so I probably will be going the transformer route.

Comment: @mweststrate actually this example explained it very well:https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/101#issuecomment-220891704 , Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone wondering how to use **Computed** in **Functional Components**.

You have to combine `useMemo()` from react and `computed()` from mobx:

TypeScript

```
import {useMemo} from 'react';
import {computed, IComputedValueOptions} from 'mobx';

// changes to "options" argument are ignored
export default function useComputed<T>(func: () => T, options?: IComputedValueOptions<T>, deps?: DependencyList)
{
    return useMemo(() => computed(func, options), deps ?? []).get();
}
```

JavaScript

```
import {useMemo} from 'react';
import {computed} from 'mobx';

// changes to "options" argument are ignored
export default function useComputed(func, options)
{
    return useMemo(() => computed(func, options), deps ?? []).get();
}
```

Example

```
export default observer(function MyComponent()
{
    const sum = useComputed(() => observableA.myValue + observableB.myValue);
    return <div>{sum}</div>
})
```

Props should be in dependencies

```
export default observer(function MyComponent({observableA, observableB})
{
    const sum = useComputed(() => observableA.myValue + observableB.myValue, null, [observableA, observableB]);
    return <div>{sum}</div>
})
```

If you don't put props in deps then `computed()` will continue using old props and it will never update.

Don't forget to wrap your components with `observer()` or it wont react to changes!

Comment: There is `useObserver` hook for this purpose

Comment: @HeilProgrammierung `useObserver` was deprecated years ago

Comment: right, I should've updated